# How to remove specific images from CIFAR-10?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I've been trying to remove specific images from the CIFAR-10 train set but have had no luck yet. Hers's what I've tried so far:

```
        data = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(name=FLAGS.dataset, batch_size=-1, data_dir=DATA_DIR))
        inputs = data['train']['image']
        labels = data['train']['label']

        inputs = (inputs/127.5)-1
        inputs = np.delete(inputs, [0, 4, 3, 2])
        labels = np.delete(labels, [0, 4, 3, 2])
```

I've a list of indices of specific images `[0, 4, 3, 2]` that I would like to remove. The shape of `inputs` is `(50000, 32, 32, 3)` and the shape of `labels` is `(50000,)`. The above method is simply not working as for some reason the shape of `input` gets nearly 5x times bigger. I'd appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for np.delete [says](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

> axis: int, optional
>
> The axis along which to delete the subarray defined
> by obj. If axis is None, obj is applied to the flattened array.

So specify the axis of samples when deleting the elements

```
inputs = np.delete(inputs, [0, 4, 3, 2], axis=0)
```